# How to create a string with special characters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

How can I create a string which contains the following:

```
<Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an escape character for the quote:

```
string temp = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Form"
```

See the msdn article for more examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

**Edit**

Correct link for C#: [C# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences)

Comment: The link in the answer goes to the C documentation. It is different to C#. E.g. C has _ASCII character in octal notation_ which C# doesn't support. But C# supports _Unicode escape sequences_ which are not supported by C. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/]

Answer (score 6):

You have two choices, depending on the remainder of the text you want to place into the string:

use the escape character `\` within the double-quoted string for any double-quote marks, as the other answers have suggested.

```
string s = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Form";
```

use the string-@ form, which avoids processing the `\` (such as in path names like `C:\Temp\Myfile.txt`), and then double the double-quote:

```
string s = @"<Object type=""System.Windows.Forms.Form";
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the backslash character to escape strings, the example below should fit your needs:

**Example:**

```
string test = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Form";
```

**MSDN Specification on String Literals / Escaping Literals:**

[MSDN : String Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691090)

Answer (score 2):

`string s = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Form";`

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Form";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use backslash to escape.

```
String str = "<Object type=\"System.Windows.Forms.Forms";
```